If $h$ is continuous and $h=g \circ f$, are $g$ and $f$ continuous?
If $h$ is continuous and $h=g \circ f$, are $g$ and $f$ continuous?
I know if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $f\circ g$ is also continuous. But I have a composition of functions and I don't have information of the functions.

Take an invertible, non-continuous function $f$, and consider $f \circ f^{-1}$...

Or let one of $f,g$ be any function, while the other is constant.

Or compose the Dirichlet function with itself.

Does this answer your question? If the composition of two functions is continuous and one of those functions is continuous, is the other function continuous as well?

No. Define $f,g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = 1$ and $f(x) = \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ (or your favourite discontinuous function). Then $(g \circ f) (x) = 1$.
